# Contar filas que cumplan una condición de filtro en Power Bi

Tags: powerbi

Para la siguiente tabla quiero **contar las filas únicamente cuyo return_reason es "DEFECTUOSO"**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que he intentado:

```
pedidos_defectuosos=
CALCULATE
     COUNT(fact_sale_order[sale_order_id]),
     dim_picking_return_reason[picking_return_reason_id] = 85
)
```

Sin embargo, no funciona puesto que si en vez de "DEFECTUOSO" pongo el ID de "CAMBIO DE MAQUINA", **el resultado que me da es exactamente el mismo**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien sabe qué podría estar ocurriendo?

También he probado con la función `COUNTROWS`, pero tampoco funciona.

Comment: En tu formula DAX tienes el id del DEFECTUOSO como 85, lo cual en tu tabla aparece como 86

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si solo queres contar defectuosos, podrías probar la siguiente métrica:

pedidos_defectuosos=
CALCULATE
COUNT(fact_sale_order[sale_order_id]),
FILTER(fact_sale_order, fact_sale_order[return_reason] = "DEFECTUOSO"))

Por otro lado, fíjate que le ID 2919877 esta repetido con 2 return reasons distintas por lo que podría ser un problema de datos ahí.